# Ranking by Groups in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to rank the following groups by 'String' and 'Is_sep' and keep the order by 'Id':
(SQL Server)

```
ID      | String    | Is_Sep    | Rank      | Rank_DESC
1       | XX        | 0         | 1         | 3
2       | XX        | 0         | 2         | 2
3       | XX        | 1         | 3         | 1
4       | XX        | 0         | 1         | 3
5       | XX        | 0         | 2         | 2
6       | XX        | 1         | 3         | 1
7       | YY        | 0         | 1         | 4
8       | YY        | 0         | 2         | 3
9       | YY        | 0         | 3         | 2
10      | YY        | 1         | 4         | 1
11      | ZZ        | 0         | 1         | 2
12      | ZZ        | 1         | 2         | 1
13      | ZZ        | 0         | 1         | 3
14      | ZZ        | 0         | 2         | 2
15      | ZZ        | 1         | 3         | 1
```

Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “ranking”? Do you mean ordering? Obtaining a row-number after ordering? Or do you mean “relevance” according to some criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kind of gaps-and-island problem, where `is_sep` marks the end of each island.

I would use a window sum to define the groups, and then `row_number()`:

```
select 
    id,
    string,
    sep,
    row_number() over(partition by string, grp order by id) rn,
    row_number() over(partition by string, grp order by id desc) rn_desc
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(is_sep) over(partition by string order by id desc) grp
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

Note that, for this sample data, you don't really need `string` in the partition, since `is_sep` also indicates the transition between `string` values. So this works equally well:

```
select 
    id,
    string,
    is_sep,
    row_number() over(partition by grp order by id) rn,
    row_number() over(partition by grp order by id desc) rn_desc
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(is_sep) over(order by id desc) grp
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac4dd6841f291baa1c7ba3f7e038f3ea)**:

```
id | string | is_sep | rn | rn_desc
-: | :----- | -----: | -: | ------:
 1 | XX     |      0 |  1 |       3
 2 | XX     |      0 |  2 |       2
 3 | XX     |      1 |  3 |       1
 4 | XX     |      0 |  1 |       3
 5 | XX     |      0 |  2 |       2
 6 | XX     |      1 |  3 |       1
 7 | YY     |      0 |  1 |       4
 8 | YY     |      0 |  2 |       3
 9 | YY     |      0 |  3 |       2
10 | YY     |      1 |  4 |       1
11 | ZZ     |      0 |  1 |       2
12 | ZZ     |      1 |  2 |       1
13 | ZZ     |      0 |  1 |       3
14 | ZZ     |      0 |  2 |       2
15 | ZZ     |      1 |  3 |       1
```

Comment: `sum(is_sep) over (partition by string order by id desc)` is really much simpler.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: ah yes, that’s much simpler indeed - no need for `coalesce()`, nor for `rows between`. Thanks!